# RecyclerView with multiselect

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a image view, onClick of this imageView a new activity with list of items with multiselect could come, I can select any number of items, the selected items should be placed back of the previous activity which has a edit box.

I have attached the picture, please help me out.

[image] 
The edit button near interested_in, on click of that it should open new activity with list of items, after selecting items, it should be brought back to interested field.

Answer (score 0):

Use onActivityResult and start new intent with startActivityForResult

Some Tutorials :

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html
- http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example